# ssh rsa key auth only occurs if I am already logged in on console

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Can't figure this out - am using id_rsa key based authentication to our servers (approximately 400 Linux and UNIX servers).

In this case I have 3 identical servers with 3 recent installs of Ubuntu 12.04 - svr1 svr2 svr3 for the sake of this discussion.

They are IBM blade servers so I have the ability of logging into a remote console.

For svr1 I can ssh in fine using my rsa key - it looks like this from the client with ssh -vvv:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mbubb/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

and env vars are set and I am in...

But for svr2 (and 3) it looks like this:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mbubb/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/mbubb/.ssh/id_dsa
```

... it cycles through other key options and finally:

```
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
   Permission denied (publickey).
```

What is curious is if I console in through the Bladecenter MM and then ssh to the server it works fine.

Looking at /var/log/auth.log on svr2 there are no entries for when I get "Permission denied". It doesn't appear to 'see' the attempt.

I checked directory permissions (homedir and sshdir) they are consistent. I compared /etc/ssh/sshd_config - they are identical.

Maybe it is PAM? Or another level of authentication.

I am intrigued by this - obviously there is something basic here I am not getting...

Comment: Should have looked in 'superuser'  http://superuser.com/questions/318233/ssh-key-authorization-only-works-if-im-already-logged-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using an encrypted home directory, then the fix is to [set up an alternate `authorized_keys` location](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting) by setting

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

in the server's `sshd_config` file so it looks somewhere other than the user's home directory for the file.

The file can be located anywhere, but you have to have the `%u` to separate users' files into their own directories so that sshd will find appropriate permissions for the directory and file.